# Remove current ViewController after instantiate and presented the next VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, rootviewcontroller

In iOS project, XCode, I have two VCs, VC1 and VC2. What I want to do is in VC1, have a button to go to VC2 using

```
let VC2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2") as! VC2
self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

After VC2 appears, I will never need to go back to VC1 so I want to remove it completely as VC1 has some downloading function that may still run in background. So I want to remove VC1. I have tried the following:

```
let VC2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2") as! VC2
self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true) {
    self.removeFromParentViewController() 
}
```

However, that does not seem to do the job as I still see the background download in progress. Is there a simple way of doing it? I do not really want to include navigation controller in this case.

Comment: I guess you could set your parentViewController to nil, again I GUESS

Comment: In `viewDidDissapear` of VC1, you should take the task and cancel it and leave the `deinit` of VC1 process for the system, that way is better and less error

Comment: How could I deinit VC1 ? I am in VC1 currently

Comment: Did you try to remove VC1 from navigation controller stack?